# Recebendo NodeList de Radio Box e verificando se esta checado para aplicar lógica

Tags: javascript

Possuo o seguinte código em JavaScript puro (não quero usar jQuery aqui):

```js
const petSize = document.querySelectorAll('.sizeRadio')

const isChecked = (checkableElement => checkableElement.checked ? true : false )

const fixUnselectedRadio = (radioToCheck, radioToUncheck) =>{
    radioToCheck.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        radioToUncheck.checked = false
    })   
}

let tamArray = petSize.forEach((tamanho, index, petSize)=>{
    if(isChecked(tamanho)){
        fixUnselectedRadio(tamanho, !tamanho )
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="tamanho mt-1 mb-2">
  <div class="form-check">
      <input class="sizeRadio form-check-input" type="radio" id="gigante" name="gigante" value="gigante" /> </input> 
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gigante">Gigante (Acima de 70cm - 45 a 60Kg)</label>
  </div>         
  <div class="form-check">
      <input class="sizeRadio form-check-input" type="radio" id="grande" name="grande" value="grande" /> </input> 
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gigante">Grande (De 50 a 69cm - 25 a 45Kg)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
      <input class="sizeRadio form-check-input" type="radio" id="medio" name="medio" value="medio" /> </input> 
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gigante">Médio (De 36cm a 49cm - 15 a 25kg)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
      <input class="sizeRadio form-check-input" type="radio" id="medio" name="medio" value="pequeno" /> </input> 
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gigante">Pequeno (De 28cm a 35cm - 6 a 15kg)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
      <input class="sizeRadio form-check-input" type="radio" id="mini" name="mini" value="mini" /> </input> 
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gigante">Mini (Abaixo de 28cm - até 6kg)</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ao executarem e tentarem selecionar os *radios*, vão perceber o que acontece: todos ficam ativos com a exceção do terceiro e quarto *radios*). **Eu preciso que apenas um fique ativo por vez** porém não consegui solucionar dessa forma e não encontrei alguma solução online!

Comment: Como você implementou a função `isChecked`? Coloque a implementação no corpo do _snippet_ do código para que possamos executá-lo.

Comment: ah perdão, não percebi que esqueci

Comment: Pronto, atualizei

Comment: Não precisa de JS para fazer isso, basta dar o mesmo `name` para os `input` do tipo `radio`, criando assim um grupo. Em cada grupo, automaticamente apenas um input poderá estar ativo de cada vez.

Comment: Cara, eu não pensei nisso :o que simples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simples de se fazer isso é compartilhar o mesmo atributo `name` entre todos os *radios* e usar o evento `change` para determinar quando algum outro campo é selecionado. Usar o `name` para isso é inclusive a forma mais recomendada de se alcançar esse resultado.

Assim:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[name="size"]')
  .forEach((field) => field.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }))
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="size" value="small" /> Pequeno
<input type="radio" name="size" value="normal" /> Normal
<input type="radio" name="size" value="large" /> Grande
```

Note acima que para diferenciar os três campos, eu uso o atributo `value`. Desse modo, serei capaz de conseguir um valor específico para cada um deles.

Comment: É exatamente isso que preciso, mais simples do que imaginei :o Muito obrigado!